# (Laravel 8.x) Force User (staff) to Logout When Username or Password Changed by Admin

Tags: laravel

Framework : Laravel 8.x (PHP)

I'm new in Laravel and making a simple web Authentication with `username` and `password` with Laravel Fortify.

I need to make User (staff) account or Admin (self or other Admin) account forced to logout when his `username` or `password` has been changed by Admin. Let say Admin username is `abc` has been changed to `admin`.

```
public function update($data, $id)
{
   $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
   $user->username = $data->input('username');
   ** some codes **
   return $user->save();
}
```

I read from documentation that i can use `$user->wasChanged('username')` to check if `username` changed and the return will be `true` then I can call some method. But I want to put it on **Middleware** like this.

```
class isUsernameChanged
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        /* 
         * I'm stuck here because Auth::user()->username just calling from DB, also generate changed username
         *
         * I think maybe I can compare it with session, but I did "dd(Session())"
         * and I don't find my username on session.
        */
        if (Auth::user()->username != ??session('username')??)
        {
            Auth::logout();
            Session::flush()
            return redirect('login')->with('msg', 'Your username has been changed by Admin, contact your supervisor to get your new username');
        }
    }
}
```

Really need some help with this.

## Edit

Sorry, I forgot to say this question is not about `isActive` middleware. Because I already setup the `isActive` user check on middleware.

I still not found any help with username changed, should I put username on Session to compare if changed ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774248/laravel-5-logout-specific-user summary: add a field to the user table, logout user if the field is true, for example: if you want to logout user with id: `User::where("id",$id)->update(["to_logout" => true])` and in middleware check if to_logout is true like above

Comment: Hi, how to make sure all browsers disconnects if I didn't put on middleware ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is define a `boolean` field on your `users` table which specifies if the `User` account is active or enabled. Something like `isAccountEnabled`, `isAccountActive` or just `isActive` etc.

```
$table->boolean('isAccountEnabled')->default(true); // or false up to you
```

When the `username` or `password` of a `User` is updated, you can set the value of `isAccountEnabled` to `false`.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // do some validation

    $user = User::firstOrFail($id);

    // update your user
    // I use all() for simplicity, you should use only() or similar
    $user->update($request->all());

    // check if either the username or password were changed
    // if so, then set our database flag to false
    if (array_intersect(['username', 'password'], $user->getChanges()) {
        $user->update(['isAccountEnabled' => false]);
    }

    // return somewhere
    return redirect(route('user.edit', $user->id));
}
```

Define a `middelware` to check the value of `isAccountEnabled` and if it is `false`, log the `User` out.

```php
class CheckIsAccountEnabled
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // check if the account is disabled 
        // if it is disabled, log the user out and redirect to login
        if (! auth()->user()->isAccountEnabled) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect(route('login'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then you can apply the `middleware` to your `routes` as you would normally.

Comment: Hi, i'm really sorry that I forgot to say about `isActive` middleware. I was used it, but now really need to force logout when username changed.

Comment: @Krizalid007 My example will log a user out if their `username` or `password` has been changed. It uses a field in the database and middleware to perform the check and determine if a `user` should be logged out.